# does window.open fail to open up a popup window sometimes?

Tags: javascript, ajax

There's an update process for something.

And I need to call a service from a third party, so that their database will be updated as well.

My Ajax works fine.
Here's the inner code snippet of success call back.

```
.
$.ajax({
.
.
     success : funtion(result) {
          .
          .
          .

          var disposalWindow = window.open('http://10.10.10.10:8070/exp_call?YMD='+ymd+'&HMS='+hms+'&CID='+cid+'&SEND_DATE='+senddate+'&ACODE='+inlineNumber+'&CALL_TYPE='+calltype, '');
          disposalWindow.close();
     },
.
.
.
```

This has worked perfectly so far. But the update process for third party was failed for the first time today.

I asked the provider to check out the log and see if the page was called or not and it processed right or not.

And the answer was "you called nothing at the time, log told me."

Could this happen?
It's been 3 month since the project was finished.

Using Ajax for calling the page isn't acceptable because of CORS.

But I thought using window.open would be no problem, which turns out to be problem, seemingly.
How can I deal with it, in this situation?

Is it an inappropriate way to use window.open for this purpose?

Comment: Popup blockers basically come with web browsers these days

Comment: Yes but, the users are supposed to allow popup in their browser. The client decided to do that way.

Comment: with this typo it hasn't been called ever: `success : funtion(result) {` -> `function` ...

Comment: and if your `ajax` doesn't succeed the `success` function won't fire. so it's much more likely that your `ajax` function did not succeed than that `window.open` has failed to work randomly.

Comment: @northkildonan Ajax was processed correctly. Our server was updated by the result. That proves the ajax was successful.

Comment: No it doesn't. A HTTP 200 response proves that the request was successful. Your server code might be failing after you update your database or log.

Comment: That said, browser usually block window.open calls unless it is being called in a click event handler. A safer way to solve your problem would be adding an iframe or an img tag to the body and removing it after load.

Comment: @UmurKontacı There's no server side process for updating the third party data. Client side, I mean scripts on browser, takes the job entirely. By the way, iFrame !! I've never thought about it. Thanks, I'm going to give it a shot.

Answer (score -1):

I've test a lot to find out what's the exact cause of this random work of url-call via window.open.

It looks like the network condition affects the result.

I hooked off the LAN cable when window.open was underway and the same error was reproduced.

Otherwise it works fine.

---

UPDATED.

Here's my code to solve this problem, inspired by Umur Kontacı's comment.

```
$.ajax({
.
.
     success : funtion(result) {
          .
          .
          .


          $("<iframe id='disposalIframe' src='http://10.10.10.10:8070/exp_callback?YMD=20141110&HMS=114113&CID=0517277176+&SEND_DATE=20141110115023&ACODE=1161&CALL_TYPE=4' width='0' height='0'></iframe>").appendTo(document.body);

          $('#disposalIframe').load(function(e) {
                $('#disposalIframe').remove();              
          });

          //var disposalWindow = window.open('http://10.10.10.10:8070/exp_call?YMD='+ymd+'&HMS='+hms+'&CID='+cid+'&SEND_DATE='+senddate+'&ACODE='+inlineNumber+'&CALL_TYPE='+calltype, '');
          //disposalWindow.close();
     },
.
.
.
```

I see it waits until the network becomes available again when I hooked off and on the cable.

In case of disconnection of network, however, it doesn't guarantee the successful call of the service.

But It makes it latency-free. I tested it.

Comment: Dear a downvoter, give me some reasons for that please ?

Comment: I also encounter `window.open` sometimes not open a tab. And I tried what you said "disconnect the network" and there is right no tab is opened in this case. However, if it is caused by network, then whatever we did, the corresponding solution still not work because our network down, right?